# UI for product set data of vision api product search

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vision-api, google-product-search

Is there any UI available in google cloud console to browse product sets created for vision api product search? I can write python script to get that data but just wondering if any UI is available that I have missed.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, there is no GUI developed for the Vision Product Search API.

However, there is this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/zinjiggle/google-product-search-simple-ui) where a user has developed his own, simple GUI for Vision Product Search API to make it more user friendly. The same user has also posted [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOdUYTO1jJY) on YouTube too describing the installation process and the way to use it.

You could try it but note that this is not an official implementation thus not supported and is not in any way affiliated with Google.